# Insert comment linked to post ID

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Trying to Insert into report_comment table ReportID and Comments into Repot_comments table

**However I now get errors**

```
 Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0) VALUES ('Report_Comments')' at line 1

INSERT INTO `Report_Comments` (0) VALUES ('Report_Comments')

Filename: models/report/Report_model.php

Line Number: 61
```

**Controller**

```
 function comment_add()
        {
                if ($query = $this->report_model->create_comment()) {

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('messagetwo', 'You added a Comment');
                    redirect('main/comments/' .$_POST['ReportID']);

                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('messagetwo', 'Sorry not this time');
                    redirect('main/comments/' .$_POST['ReportID']);
                }
        }
```

**Model**

```
function create_comment()
{

    $new_comment = array(
        'Comments', $_POST => $this->input->post('Report_Comments')
    );

    $insert = $this->db->insert('Report_Comments', $new_comment);
    return $insert;
}
```

**View**

```
    <p><?= anchor('main', 'Back home'); ?></p>

    <?= form_open('main/comment_add'); ?>

    <?= form_hidden('ReportID', $this->uri->segment(3)); ?>

    <p><textarea name="Comments" rows="10"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="add comment"/></p>

    <?php
    if ($this->session->flashdata('messagetwo')) {
        ?>
        <div class="message flash">
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('messagetwo'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

    </form>
```

Comment: The duplicate also applies to column names.

Comment: Its not a duplicate, I deleted the old question as i felt it made no sense and was a mess. I have re- written the question and have changed the code.

Comment: `right syntax to use near '0)` and and your query is this `(0) VALUES ('Report_Comments')`, therefore it is a duplicate.

Comment: Can  you share your table structure

Comment: Ok, i understand. but i deleted the old question to make sure i did not duplicare

Comment: use ticks `\`` around the column name and it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- Ill give it a go.

Comment: @Beep You're welcome.

Comment: Not quite, but il keep trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your:

```
$new_comment = array(
        'Comments', $_POST => $this->input->post('Report_Comments')
    );
```

Check with a `var_dump($new_comment)`, the first index should be 0;

Try that:

```
$new_comment = array(
        'Comments' => $this->input->post('Report_Comments')
    );
```

Assuming your field is "Comments" and `$this->input->post('Report_Comments')` return a valid string.

[Here is the documentation of $this->db->insert() for codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)

Comment: that is  the error, how would i do this in the code ?

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope that will help you.